# Using ArcGIS for Server and ArcSDE for importing shapefiles?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, shapefile, enterprise-geodatabase, import

Is there a way to use ArcGIS Server web services to perform the task below?

I have .NET ArcObjects code to import shapefiles to Spatial DB which works on ArcGIS for Desktop.

This code used ArcSDE to parse several folders and import into Spatial DB.

What kind of ArcGIS for Server web service can I use to web enable this functionality?

Browser will have a login credentials and just needs to show progress of importing and failure/error conditions in browser.

Comment: Have you made this code into a geoprocessing tool? Porting a Desktop GP tool to Server can be as simple as registering the data store.

Answer (score 2):

Just as Vince said...A simple tool built with model builder (using featureclass to featureclass or similar), then published to ArcGIS Server, would do the trick.

Comment: Vince/Jason..making tool as GP may not help in my context.I have 30K lines of code doing various activities further in my automated work flow.Functionality in my query will evolve -something like making use of FeautreCompare to know if 2 cycles of data are changed and import only the delta.Then perform QC with custom rules etc...It is going to be lot of check points with users interacting via browser and making go,no go decisions.It does not involve vector map editing though.Appreciate if you could help me